# ¿Como se realizaria esta consulta en LinQ?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework, linq

Tengo las siguientes relaciones entre tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de las cuales me interesa traer **las mesas que no estan reservadas el dia que el cliente marque para realizarla (ademas de que no deberia listar las mesas en las cuales su estado sea igual a 2 que es inactiva, ni tener en cuenta las reservas eliminadas que tendrian el estado 3)**.
Me recomendaron usar la sentencia `any()`, con lo que me quedo algo asi, que es mas o menos lo que busco (pero no funciona, ya que me trae las mesas OCUPADAS ese dia)

```
BBDD.MesaXReserva.Include("Reserva").Include("Mesa").Where(Identificador => !Identificador.Mesa.MesaXReserva.Any()
                        && Identificador.Reserva.ID_EstadoReserva != (int)ClsEstadoReservas.EEstadosReservas.Eliminada
                        && Identificador.Reserva.Fecha == _FechaReservar
                        && Identificador.Mesa.ID_EstadoMesa != (int)ClsEstadosMesas.EEstadosMesas.Inactivo).ToList();
```

En SQL me quedo la siguiente consulta (que le falta el filtrado por estados de reservas y mesas que seguro lo podria hacer con `LinQ` una vez traido los datos)

```sql
select * from Mesa 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select MesaXReserva.ID_Mesa FROM
    MesaXReserva INNER JOIN Reserva 
    on Reserva.ID_Reserva = MesaXReserva.ID_Reserva 
    WHERE Reserva.Fecha = CAST('21/09/2019' as date)
) as Ocupada 
on mesa.ID_Mesa = Ocupada.ID_Mesa 
WHERE Ocupada.ID_Mesa is NULL
```

con la que me devuelve los datos que necesito (con una fecha fija en este caso).

Comment: No es recomendable que uses linq para consultas donde se involucran demasiados datos, es mejor que elabores un Stored Procedure y lo llames desde linq to sql

Comment: Me dijeron que con any no es tan complicado, era porque queria mantener las consultas con linq. ¿como se haria con un Stored Procedure? (para tenerlo en cuenta, nunca las use hasta ahora),

Comment: linq es mejor utilizarlo a un objeto con datos listos (`dataSet,list,etc`), no es muy recomendable usarlo para consultas con tantos datos con relaciones entre tablas. yo haria un **sp** o un metodo que traiga los datos, y para filtrarlos u ordenarlos a tu placer usar **linq**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería una cosa parecida a esto para traer todas las mesas sin reserva

```
var mesasConReserva = context.Mesa.Include(r => r.Reserva).Where(m => (m.Reserva.Fecha == fechaUsuario) && ( m.Reserva.IdEstadoReserva != 2 && m.Reserva.IdEstadoReserva != 3));

var mesasSinReserva = context.Mesa.Where(m => !mesasConReserva.Any(r => r.IdMesa == m.IdMesa));
```